# How to create a custom VirtualizingPanel on Windows Phone 8.1 / Windows 10?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to do this in Windows 10 and Windows Phone 8.1 [(app link)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/flat-notes/9wzdncrdd0xx):

I have a custom class called FluidPanel that extends Panel and overrides methods MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride. **The goal is to create the [Google Keep appearence](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-fe0dRRpIBOA/UUn4csouc_I/AAAAAAAAAAk/mlPjcSkqL1k/s1600/blog-hero.png). Ok, it's working fine.**

But, because I'm using a **basic Panel as the ItemsPanelTemplate**, the items Reorder doesn't work. Also, transistions doesn't work and it doesn't virtualize.

So, I would like to know how to **create a custom panel that reorder items and virtualize just like the GridView's ItemsWrapGrid**.

I tried to extends the class VirtualizingPanel, but it keeps showing me this error that looks like a bug:

> 'VirtualizingPanel' does not contain a constructor that takes 0
>   arguments

Hope someone can give some directions.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t inherit from the “VirtualizingPanel” in C# is because it is a Windows Runtime Class and there is no constructor function exposed by the Windows metadata (windows.winmd file).
The UI virtualizing is only a concept, it will be a little complex, but it is possible to implement it from scratch.
I think the blog series implementing a virtualized panel in WPF will be a good start.

Part#1: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/06/526310.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20140422150804/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/06/526310.aspx)

Part#2: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/13/531550.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119135752/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/13/531550.aspx)

Part#3: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/14/532333.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20151101130018/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/14/532333.aspx)

P.S: the blog is about WPF, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it! But I shouldn't have focused on the virtualization part, the Reorder and Transition is the real problem I'm facing. I'm gonna delete this question. Please see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623799/custom-panel-with-reorder-and-animations-transitions

Comment: @Jeffrey I know its an old thread, but I really need to create a customize virtualizing panel.The VirtualizingTilePanel in the article you mentioned is derived from VirtualizingPanel, and implemented IScrollInfo. So which class should I derive from in UWP or Windows store apps if VirtualizingPanel can not be extend? Do I have to create it as Windows Runtime Class too using c++? thx!