# Custom Panel with Reorder and animations / transitions

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have a custom class called FluidPanel that extends **Panel** and overrides methods MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride. The goal is to create the Google Keep appearence. Ok, it's working fine. ([app link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/flat-notes/9wzdncrdd0xx))

But, because I'm extending a basic **Panel** and using it as the ItemsPanelTemplate, I'm missing 2 things: Reorder and some transitions, that simply doens't work out of the box. See code:

```
<GridView CanReorderItems="True" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True">
    <GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition FromVerticalOffset="200" IsStaggeringEnabled="True"/>
            <ReorderThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>

    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:FluidPanel/><!--custom panel = reorder doesn't work-->
            <!--<StackPanel/>--><!--reorder and animations work normally (reorder to see)-->
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>

    <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Red"/>
    <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
    <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Blue"/>
    <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Orange"/>
    <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Purple"/>
    <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Pink"/>
</GridView>
```

So, the main question is: How to create a custom Panel with Reorder fully working, including animations? (like that offset to the left/right/...)

A second (less important) question is: And with the EntranceThemeTransition working?

Answer (score 1):

I partially found the solution.
Unfortunately it's not as easy as it should be.

For custom Panels, it seems that we have to implement the Reorder manually, listening to the drag & drop events.

Here is an article about it: [Extending GridView with Drag and Drop](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/536519/Extending-GridView-with-Drag-and-Drop-for-Grouping)
and here is a [simplified code](https://github.com/joakimhallberg/VBStats/blob/b63314f6feedb68613e8491ba89708c83b5e716c/VolleyballStats/VolleyballStats.Windows/Controls/DragDropListView.cs) about it.

The reorder animation is added by manually changing the Visual State:

```
private void OnDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Note;
    if (item == null) return;

    e.Data.Properties["targetItem"] = item;

    var itemContainer = (sender as ItemsControl).ContainerFromItem(item) as Control;
    if (itemContainer == null) return;

    VisualStateManager.GoToState(itemContainer, "BottomReorderHint", true);
}
```

But I still hope there is any easier way to do it, giving the fact that a lot of Panels implement it (StackPanel, ItemsWrapGrid, ...).

Still can't get the EntranceThemeTransition to work on the custom panel.
**EDIT:** [workaround to make EntranceThemeTransition works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635177/how-to-make-entrancethemetransition-works-on-a-custom-panel-itemssource/31735937#31735937)

Comment: It's worth noting that all transitions DO work with custom panels. Try for example, the WrapPanel here: [link]https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/WrapPanel/WrapPanel.cs[/link] . Presumably then, whatever is killing and transitions is either some idiosyncrasy in your Measure / Arrange logic (are you forcing re-arranges?), or your ItemsSource bindings are being applied more than once. (And to support Re-order your ItemsSource needs to implement INotifyCollectionChanged and be throwing something like CollectionChanged.Moved)

Comment: You are correct Johnny, but the EntranceThemeTransition doesn't. You can try it using StackPanel as a custom panel or the WrapPanel you posted. I found out an workaround, edited the post with the link!