# Can not inherit from VirtualizingPanel or OrientedVirtualizingPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, custom-panel

I want to create a customized virtualizing panel which can be used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl in Windows Store apps or UWP project. I thought it's would be the easiest way to inherit and extend VirtualizingPanel or OrientedVirtualizingPanel. But both said they 'does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments'. Does it mean that they can not be inherited? If so, then which class should I extend?

```
public class MyOrientedVirtualizingPanel : VirtualizingPanel
{
    //compile error: VirtualizingPanel does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
    public MyOrientedVirtualizingPanel()
    {


    }
}
```

Comment: I've already implemented that as you done,but there is no error accrued.

Comment: According to [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31507686/1136211), it won't work.

Comment: @Clemens I'm useing the article mention in this Q/A(VirtualizingTilePanel) as the sample. It is derived from VirtualizingPanel, and implemented IScrollInfo. Can you give me some idea which class should I derive in Windows Store apps or UWP if VirtualizingPanel can't be extent?thx

Comment: @Saman Can you shed more light on this topic? How to fix this compile error?thx